# How to declares types for an object with method?

Tags: typescript

I have an object as follows -

```
type Person = {
  firstname: string,
  lastname: string,
}

let person: Person = {
   firstname: "John",
   lastname: "Doe",
   fullname: function() {
     return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`
   }
}
```

How to declare type for fullname method?

Comment: `fullname(): string` should work, no? If you didn't already, please see [the language documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html) for the basics; if you did read the docs and something there didn't make sense or didn't work for you, be specific about it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much typing you want.

**Option 1**

If you want something that will tell you exactly what's the `fullName()` function returning, you can use generics and template literals to achieve it, like so:

```
type Person<FirstNameT extends string, LastNameT extends string> = {
  firstname: FirstNameT,
  lastname: LastNameT,
  fullname: () => `${FirstNameT} ${LastNameT}`
}

let person: Person<"John", "Doe"> = {
   firstname: "John",
   lastname: "Doe",
   fullname: function() {
     return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}` // typed as () => "John Doe"
   }
}
```

**Option 2**

If you aren't concerned about the literal type of the return you can use something simpler like:

```
type Person = {
  firstname: string,
  lastname: string,
  fullname: () => `${Person["firstname"]} ${Person["lastname"]}`
}

let person: Person = {
   firstname: "John",
   lastname: "Doe",
   fullname: function() {
     return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}` // typed as () => `${string} ${string}`
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems here :

1. You are creating an object of type `Person`. You cannot add the fullName attribute as it is not defined in the `Person` type.
2. You are calling `this` inside an object. The keyword `this`, refers to the calling context, meaning that `this`, will in your case refor to the `window`.

One simple solution :

Create a class! This will allow you to implement your fullname method, and use the `this` keyword, which will then refer to your class instance!

A simple implementation to your problem would then be:

```
class Person {
  private firstName: string;
  private lastName: string;

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public fullName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}


const johnDoe: Person = new Person('John', 'Doe');

console.log(johnDoe.fullName()); // "John Doe"
```